# How to use Realm's in method with Kotlin

Tags: android, realm, kotlin

I'm trying to do something like:

```
val barcodes = arrayOf("123", "456", "789")
realm.where(Product::class.java).in("barcode", barcodes).findAll()
```

However "in" is a Kotlin function and I can't access the in(String filedName, String[] values) method of RealmQuery object.

Currently I have a java class that does the job and returns the result, but I was wondering is there a more graceful workaround for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated in the [Escaping for Java identifiers that are keywords in Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#escaping-for-java-identifiers-that-are-keywords-in-kotlin):

> Some of the Kotlin keywords are valid identifiers in Java: in, object,
>   is, etc. If a Java library uses a Kotlin keyword for a method, you can
>   still call the method escaping it with the backtick (`) character

For example:

```
realm.where(Product::class.java).`in`("barcode", barcodes).findAll()
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast :) Thanks!

Comment: If escaping the method name all the time is inconvenient for you, ypu have the possibility to create an extension function with a slightly different name that delegates to `in`.